# Is it possible to open the Translation Editor using a different xml instead of strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml

I have my strings stored in different .xml(s). Now, I need to do some translations for them and I was wondering **if it is possible to open the Translation Editor for those xml**. I tried but it only appears on the `strings.xml`

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What the exact problem ??

Comment: I am trying to open the Translations Editor in a xml that is not named strings.xml but contain strings in it.

Comment: yes, the Translations Editor that is built in Android Studio. The one that is in the context menu when you right click strings.xml. I was wondering if it is possible to open it using a differently named xml.

Comment: @Strauss it's not depends on file name. must be display all string.. show me screenshots of your string file and translations editor. I am curious why you not able to see

Comment: @Strauss why you not using strings.xml ???

Comment: Why is this question downvotted? Android Studio build-in translation editor can't properly work with multiple strings names e.q. strings_coutries.xml, . It can only handle files with name strings.xml.

Comment: I have some problem, i have strings2.xml file and i want it to open the Translation editor for this file, but is missing in context menu(right click on the file).

Comment: @Balflear I suggest just open the context menu from the strings.xml. The Translator Editor will contain all the strings in your resource folder.

Answer (score 4):

This is old, but I figured something out that may be helpful for anyone looking.

1. When you open the Translations Editor for a module, it will show all strings in the res folder, not just the "strings.xml" file.  So if you have other .xml files with strings, they will be listed.
2. The Android Studio UI only allows the Translation Editor to be opened from the "strings.xml" file.  So if you have a module that has strings files without any xml file named "strings.xml" just create a blank "strings.xml" file in that res folder and use that to open the Translations Editor - it will list all strings.

Comment: Translations Editor can be opened not only from the `strings.xml` file, but from any file [that ends with](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/de74306d3ba47d5a7af4e9a4fae7959b55da4ca3/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/editors/strings/StringResourceEditorProvider.java#39) "strings.xml" (e.g. `international-strings.xml` will also work)

Comment: The problem is that the editor is unique for all files. If a string is defined in `international-strings.xml` and you add a translation via the editor, it will be added in the `strings.xml` of the other locale instead of adding it in `international-strings.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly, you don't need to open separate files in translation editor.

1. Open your `something.xml` file
2. Alt + Enter on any item -> Override resource in other configuration
3. Select Locale and press the button ">>"
4. Choose locale needed.

This will create localization file for your `something.xml` file.

5. `something.xml` -> copy all innards -> paste into localization file.
6. If you remove all values from localization file, and than open your main `strings.xml` file with editor, you will find there the words from `something.xml` untranslated. If you won't, you will find similar values for original and new locale.

When you open in editor your `strings.xml`, Studio puts there all string resources from the current module, despite you put your strings in multiple files. Maybe this is not as handy, as it would be with opening files one by one, but this still good, if you just need to make sure you didn't miss any string to be translated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open any layout
2. Find this panel by image panel

   [image]
3. Click on earth icon
4. Click "Edit translations"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question on how to edit translations in XML files other than `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I have pretty big translation database, almost 1k positions on every single language. And every module has its own prefix, so my string files look like this: **prefix_strings_hitory.xml, prefix_strings_news.xml, prefix_strings_coutries.xml** etc. Android Studio translation editor **can't** handle properly translations with files different than strings.xml.

That's how am I doing this:

1.In every module create empty file strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
</resources>
```

Thanks to this you can open editor easy.

2.Now assume you want to have file named *values/abc_strings_main_activity.xml*, create it.

3.When we need german translation, you have to **manualy** make a copy of your original (default) file: *values-de/abc_strings_main_activity.xml*. If you let Translation Editor copy your file, it would create *values-de/strings.xml* instead and put your strings there.

4.Now when you use Translation Editor, it would be properly saving your string in correct files and positions.

5.When I make a copy of my file, I always use file with empty  tags body, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="abc__button_1"></string>
        <string name="abc__tile"></string>
        <string name="abc__share"></string>
    </resources>
```

Thanks to it, I can see empty (not translated) cells in Translation Editor

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3
Opening the "translation editor" window I've realized that all entries from different resource file (strings.xml, otherTranslationFile.xml and so on...) are listed.
In the example I've used a prefix "c_"  to better sort and recognize that specific entries

[image]

Comment: Please add more info in detail.

Comment: @bhansa He is saying that editor is for all strings_XXXXX files you have in project